# Nested table with data tables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables-1.10

I have the following nested HTML table. I am using the Datatables API to make my tables searchable. One problem I have faced is with the nested tables I'm not sure how to make the nested tables searchable? I have tried adding additional ID tags to the nested tables HTML code and adding that into the dataTables JS code call but that did not work. Any idea how to make the sub-tables searchable?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>


<div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>TC NAME</th>
                <th>NS FLOW</th>
                <th>SN FLOW</th>
                <th>NS FLOW</th>
                <th>SN FLOW</th>
                <th>NS FLOW</th>
                <th>SN FLOW</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>721</td>
                <td>3/15/20</td>

                <td>
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>600</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>400</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>


                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>





        <tr>
                <td>722</td>
                <td>3/16/20</td>

                <td>
                    <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>600</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>400</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>


                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>




        <tr>
                <td>633</td>
                <td>3/17/20</td>

                <td>
                    <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TC3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>600</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>400</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>


                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                 <table class="table table-nostriped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you by "searchable" mean DataTables inside DataTables you can use the `createdRow` callback to initialize tables inside a `<tr>`'s columns.

You must have a `columns` section in order to compensate for the missing `<thead>` in the nested tables (avoiding the *TypeError: col is undefined* error) :

```js
const columns = [
  { title: '' },
]
```

Init the nested tables in the `createdRow` callback:

```js
let table = $('#example').DataTable({
  createdRow: function(row) {
    $(row).find('td table')
      .DataTable({
        columns: columns,
        dom: 'tf'
      })
  }
})
```

Notice the `dom` section. Here only showing the table itself and the filter box. You 
can remove the header with

```css
table.dataTable td table thead {
  display: none;
}
```

Dont add this CSS if you want sortable columns in the nested tables.

demo using the markup in question -> **http://jsfiddle.net/davidkonrad/8pzkr6yn/**

---

**Update**. If your concern just is to be able to search within the content of the nested tables (e.g the HTML markup scraped away) just define the relevant columns `type` as `'html'` (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) :

```js
let table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: [2,3,4,5,6,7], type: 'html' },
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, one question though would it be possible to have a single search rather than have multiple searches in the nested table?

Comment: @Matt, I knew I was overkilling :) If you just want to search the content of the table, it is really easy. See update.

Comment: Thanks for this i was able to get this working with your suggestion. I put this jsFiddle together as well showing the fix. https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/4hsj91ya/24/